# DB_HOST - is LOCALHOST speedy than domain name?

Tags: sql, hosting

I am interested, 
on some hosting(although they are paid hostings, and even the `domain.com` DNS nameservers are pointed to that hosting), you have to insert: `mysql.domain.com` (instead of: `localhost`) , and i was afraid, that connecting to `mysql.domain.com` will be much slower... 
Am I right?

p.s.

Comment: Here discussed - http://serverfault.com/questions/705773/mysql-is-localhost-speedy-than-i-e-domain-mysql-domain-com

Answer (score 1):

Usually you only have to use mysql.domain.com if connecting to a remote database. If that is what you are doing, then yes. It will be slower than a locally hosted database. Even if the domain resolves to the local server localhost should resolve quicker as it uses the loopback interface which bypasses network hardware.